# Triggering word-wrap: break-word in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` that contains a `<p>` in which I want to, when the p is larger than the users' screen (eg a user intentionally posts a long string of characters to break the page layout), cause word-wrap.

The current method I have in place works okay; setting the `<div>`'s css to `width: 97%`, and the `<p>` to `word-wrap: break-word`; but this produces unwanted results if an image is put into the div that exceeds the width (high-resolution images-expanded in place), the image extends outside of the post. I of course don't want to set `overflow: hidden/scroll` on the `<div>`, because that would obscure the image.

Is there any way to trigger `word-wrap: break-word` in a way that will solve both of these problems? Or perhaps another CSS-based solution?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what control you have over the user-generated content, you may be able to apply a style to their images (e.g., to all img tags that are a child of the container holding your user's content).

Assuming you can add your own styling to their images, you might be able to do something using max-width.

Answer (score -1):

Wrapping should be default behavior, but try setting your DIV's white-space to normal

```
white-space:normal;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp